# About upload image in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, upload, pug

I was seen some stackoverflow about this question.

In the jade.

```
form.editUserForm(name="editUser", action="/upload", method="post")
    input(placeholder="Select you photo" type="file", name="thumbnail")
    input.ui.blue.submit.button(type="submit", value="Submit")
```

In the js.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
}
```

I found the 'req.files' is 'undefined', so I cannot use the code below.

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var tmp_path = req.files.thumbnail.path;
    target_path = '/tmp/' + req.files.thumbnail.name;
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What middleware are you using above that route?

Comment: I try to use the 'formidable', I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the `enctype` attribute of your form to the value `multipart/form-data`:

```
form.editUserForm(name="editUser", action="/upload", method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data")
```

Comment: Some solution said 'express 4.0 not support the req.files'